# Error "SOQL OFFSET clause is not supported in Batch Apex"

Tags: apex, batch

I am having 2 queries (as efficient as it could get so can change it) in a method which would return results more than 50k+. In order to solve this issue I wrote a batch class with custom iterator since it was not possible to process 2 object using standard batch job. In my custom iterator to keep track of records I made use of OFFSET so that I can process records in subsets. But I get Error "SOQL OFFSET clause is not supported in Batch Apex". I checked online documentation and it mentions of not using OFFSET keyword within a batch class but I am using OFFSET keyword in a query which is part of another class.

Want to understand if executing a query which has OFFSET keyword as part of batch transaction will throw the above error even when the query is executed in a different class. If yes please can some one let me know other alternative solution to this problem.

Example simple code that throws error:

```
global class BatchClass implements Database.Batchable<Account> {

global Iterable<Account> start(Database.batchableContext info){
return new example();
}
global void execute(Database.batchableContext info, List<Account> scope){

}
global void finish(Database.batchableContext info){
}
}

global class example implements iterable<Account>{
global Iterator<Account> Iterator(){
return new CustomIterable();
}
}

global class CustomIterable implements Iterator<Account>{
List<Account> accs {get; set;}
Integer i {get; set;}
public CustomIterable(){
accs = [SELECT id, name, numberofEmployees FROM Account WHERE name = 'false' OFFSET 0];
i = 0;
}
global boolean hasNext(){
if(i >= accs.size())
return false;
else
return true;
}
global Account next(){
if(i == 8){ i++; return null;}
i=i+1;
return accs[i-1];
}
}
```

Comment: Using `OFFSET 0` does literally nothing. Why not just remove this clause?

Comment: Also if you're batching over `SObject` records then using a custom iterable is inordinately complicated for no benefit (and many drawbacks).

Comment: @AdrianLarson I added OFFSET 0 for the example purpose to replicate the Error “SOQL OFFSET clause is not supported in Batch Apex”. In my application example OFFSET value is dynamically set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a custom iterable won't help you here; when you do so, you're limited to 50,000 rows, just like any other normal transaction. Instead, you're going to have to find either a way to query part of the data in the execute method, or two batchables, or some other technique.

Comment: my idea behind using custom iterable was that since I had to process two queries which would return more than 50k+, I was planning to create a wrapper Iterator<WrapperObject> this wrapper object would than get the result of the both the objects which would be decided by the OFFSET ex: Select Id From ObjectA where Id = '' Limit 1000 OFFSET : dynamicSize. The offset size would be decided by the records processed in the batch and that would be maintained by Database.Stateful interface. Could not use 2 batch jobs as both the values are needed in sync for processing. Not sure of a better technique.

Comment: @nevrekar_amey Offset is only going to get you to 2,000 rows of data anyways. You really need to come up with an alternative solution. Consider sorting by some value and using cutoff values to determine the next part.

Comment: oops didn't think about that any other technique you could suggest ?

Comment: @nevrekar_amey Without knowing more about what your'e *actually* trying to do, I don't know exactly how to help you. There's at least two possible techniques I could think of. Perhaps you could ask a new question that simply explains what you're trying to do?